# iPhone iOS retrieving NSMutableArray from CoreData using a function

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a function which returns an `NSMutableArray` which is fetched from `CoreData`.

```
- (NSMutableArray*)getArray:(NSString*)entityName withDescriptor:(NSString*)descriptorKey {
    NSError **error = nil;
    NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [request setEntity:entityDescription];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:descriptorKey ascending:YES];
    [request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
    [sortDescriptor release];

    return [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:error] mutableCopy];
}
```

When i `Build and Analyze` my project containing this function, i get a analyzer result saying that there is a potential leak of an object allocated at line X (the line is where it returns the mutable copy)

I am calling this function like this:

```
myArray = [self getArray:ENTITY_PAGES withDescriptor:DEFAULT_DESCRIPTOR];
```

where `myArray` is a NSMutableArray property of the class, `ENTITY_PAGES` and `DEFAULT_DESCRIPTOR` are NSString constants

I wish to use this function in more than one place so i can reduce the amount of redundancy in my project.

How should i populate `myArray` from `Core Data` using a function like this without getting these analyzer problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The analyzer is complaining about a potential memory leak because your function is violating one the objective-c memory management rules:

You take ownership of an object if you create it using a method whose name begins with “alloc” or “new” or contains “copy” (for example, alloc, newObject, or mutableCopy), or if you send it a retain message.

Change the name of your function appropriately (and make sure you release the returned array at some point) and the analyzer should stop complaining.

Here is the link to the memory management guide:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html

Comment: i added `autorelease` after `mutableCopy` and the analyzer did not complain.  i don't know what you mean by "change the name of your function appropriately".. tell me what would be appropriate?! ha

Comment: If you want your function to return a copy of the array, you need to name the function according to the memory management rules.  The name must begin with "alloc", "new", or contain "copy".

Comment: I should be a little more clear.  In your original example the caller of your function is taking ownership of the returned object (the mutable copy of the array) and needs to release it.  In this case you need to name the function appropriately.

Comment: so you're saying the function name could/should be called `(NSMutableArray*)allocArray:(NSString*)entityName...`

Comment: Yes, that will make the analyzer happy with your original implementation.  But if you change the function to autorelease the array then the caller would not take ownership and you should not change the function name.